# google_auth and Dart 2

Tags: web, dart, google-oauth, google-authentication

i am trying to create a webapp that uses google apis and needs to authenticate the user with the google auth api. so i got the example at

https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis_examples/tree/master/drive_search_web

and tried to run it. i use webstorm and dart 2.0.0-dev.68.0. the webpage can be called, but the code never runs into the then-part of authorizedClient in main-function and also gives me no popup window where i can login to google services.

i have disabled the popupblocker and i am also aware of the blocked popup when it tries to show. nothing of this kind happens.

meanwhile i have rewritten the example to use await / async instead of Future, so that i can better see, where it stops working. the code looks like this:

```
Future<auth.AutoRefreshingAuthClient> authorizedClient(ButtonElement loginButton, auth.ClientId id, scopes)
async {
  loginButton.text = "lets go!";

  auth.BrowserOAuth2Flow flow = await auth.createImplicitBrowserFlow(id, scopes);
  loginButton.text = "i am flowing";
  auth.AutoRefreshingAuthClient client;
  try
  {
    loginButton.text = "give it a try...";
    client = await flow.clientViaUserConsent(immediate: true);
    loginButton.text = "i tried it!";
  }
  catch (e)
  {
    loginButton.text = "i failed so bad!";
    client = null;
  }

  if (client == null)
  {
    loginButton.text = "no client available";
    {
      loginButton.text = "give me rights!";
      client = await flow.clientViaUserConsent(immediate: false);
    }
  }

  return client;
}
```

when i run this code, the display on the loginButton changes to "give it a try..." and then nothing more happens. it seems that the function flow.clientViaUserConsent is running forever not even creating an error so that the text "i failed so bad!" is not shown.

is the support of google_auth in dart 2 broken or is the example on github not up to date with the current dart development?

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile i managed to make it run. The main problem was the development webserver from WebStorm that always gets an random port at startup. For google authentication there must be a url in the api-console of the web-project that is linked to the calling domain, including the port. The port must not be a wildcard.

Now i start the development server by myself using always the same port, that i also placed in the authorized javascript origins in the api-console of google. After doing this the login worked.